# What hook do I need to save a setting?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I've added a new field onto the `discussion`'s section on the `/wp-admin/options-discussion.php` page that outputs along with this:

```
<?php do_settings_sections('discussion'); ?>
```

How can I hook the `Save Changes` button so that I can handle saving my new setting's fields?
I've tried `updated_option` like so:

```
add_action('updated_option', [__CLASS__, 'sanitize_settings'], 11, 3);
```

But I don't think this is what I need.

Comment: Do you want to save your data in `wp_options`?

Comment: Yes, that would work

Answer (score 0):

for saving data in `wp_options` you should set the name and value together
for example first we can add new options with `add_option` function and [see this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/)

```
add_option( 'nameOfYourOption', 'value', '', 'yes' );
```

then you can easily access your data with the `get_option` function and [see this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)

```
$yourOption = get_option( 'nameOfYourOption' );
var_dump($yourOption)
```

and if you want to change the value you can do that with `update_option` function and [see this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)

```
update_option( 'nameOfYourOption', 'newValue' );
```

With these three functions, you can manage your option
but if you try just using the hook for `update_option` [see this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option/)

```
do_action( 'update_option', string $option, mixed $old_value, mixed $value )
```

---

**Updated**

When you try to click on a Save button to using those functions, you can handle that with a form or with WordPress ajax

```html
<form method="post">

<button name="uniqName" type="submit">Save Changes</button>

</form>
```

in wordpress/php

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['uniqName'])){
//do something
}
```

and if you try to send data with ajax, just [see this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114095/jquery-ajax-sending-data-to-php)

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the `update_option` code to fire when I click the `Save Changes`  button?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can do this with a form or ajax, as I mentioned above

Comment: thank you, but I'm trying to figure out what `action` hook is called on this ( https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-discussion.php)  page's save. When I click `Save Changes` on that page there should be some sort of action hook that runs that I can use to fire a callback and then save my newly added custom fields into a `wp_option`. If that makes sense?